# Trying to play background music on android app

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I am currently trying to build an app which has to specifically use an Asynchronous task. From what I understand, an async task will run the code regardless of the UI that is being generated, but when I see it getting implemented, it has to be implemented in the onStart, onResume methods, which are inevitably tied up to one Activity. not sure if I am getting this wrong. Also, trying to run my class that is the Music Player class but it is getting stuck on declaring the Media Player, and this is a copy and paste from another statement from my code that actually works. here is the code:

```
package mt.edu.mcast.clickermaster;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class MusicPlayer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.FluteMusic);
    player.setLooping(true);
    player.setVolume(1.0f,1.0f);
    player.start();
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

}

The error is saying "Cannot resolve method 'create(MusicPlayer,int)", and yes, I have 'FluteMusic' in the raw folder

I appreciate anyone who will lend a hand :)

Comment: If your purpose is to separate music player from your UI, (like user put the music app down and browse web), then you should use `Service`. `AsyncTask` may seem it's a good option, but it actually serves a different purpose :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.FluteMusic);
```

returns  "Cannot resolve method 'create(MusicPlayer,int)" because the first element you pass, `this`, is a reference to your AsyncTask, and there are no methods in the MediaPlayer class that take an AsyncTask as a parameter.

What I guess you are trying to do by putting this, is to pass a Context as a parameter. You could have a constructor in your AsyncTask in order to keep a reference to a Context.

```
public class MusicPlayer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

Context mContext;

public MusicPlayer(Context context){
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.FluteMusic);
    player.setLooping(true);
    player.setVolume(1.0f,1.0f);
    player.start();
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

Comment: #legend...Any idea on what I can do with regards to how I can make it run on every activity without needing to use onPause, onStop, onResume and others, in every activity?

Comment: as Saehun suggested, for background tasks that doesn't necessarily require UI you should look into Services : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Only problem is that I am specifically told to use Async task. I know its bet to use service, but I need to make sure that I use an Async task. Am I getting something wrong? I'm a noob at this